# How to draw sequentially on multiple Canvases without relying on OnDraw() / invalidate() approaches?

Tags: android, canvas, uwp, opengl-es, drawing

My problem is quite simple. I need to update simultaneously  7 ECG channels @250Hz (4ms) - theoretical - (where each channel is modeled in a custom view - in Android / UserControl - in Windows UWP Win2D).

The idea is that I cannot rely on .invalidate() approach (calling 7 x .invalidate() for each Canvas/View) because *after calling Invalidate(), the OnDraw() will be called at some time in the future* [docs]. So, it isn't a deterministic way to draw "simultaneously". (improper said -> let's say **sequentially**).

My app will have different switchable layouts: Each channel in a row ( 7 rows on a page ) ; 2 x 3 + 1 ( photo attached ) ; A single channel (on a page)

**How can I achieve my plan, using a modular way of updating/drawing each channel "in the same time" ?** [in Android, but also a solution in Windows UWP is welcome]

My variants (not very efficient):

1. Having a single Canvas (a "big" screen), and drawing each logical ECG Channel in regions. This is not very modular, as I will need a Canvas for each layout. (rows layout/columns layout/single channel layout). Then, calling 1 x .Invalidate(), in order to redraw the entire canvas ... + time consuming...
2. I don't know if OpenGL could help me with a low-level drawing approach.

I need something like this (taken from a C++ approach - CClientDC dc) :

```
dc.MoveTo(ptStart);
dc.LineTo(ptEnd);
```

Calling a routine containing those commands for each "Channel" will guarantee that after receiving new values for each channel (byte[7] ), they will be redrawed sequentially, in a deterministic way.

```
for(int i=0; i<7; i++) ecgChannel[i].update(newAmplitude[i]);
```

[7 ECG Channels - layout example - photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCeiQ.png)

Comment: Time to consider your goal in more detail; it will require some clarification. ECG updates at 250Hz. Most screens update considerably slower, at 60Hz. So, right off the bat, it's impossible for the screen to synchronously render ever single update the ECG gets. Also, since (practically all) hardware uses some sort of back-buffering/page-flipping scheme, and screens have finite draw times, there is always a non-zero delay between when the data becomes available in RAM, and when the rendered data hits the eye of the viewer.

Comment: So, what I'm saying is, when you choose to `invalidate()` a `View`, and Android promises to give you an `onDraw()` "sometime in the future", you must understand that it's going to schedule you for the earliest screen refresh it possibly can, subject to how heavily the processor is loaded, the screen refresh rate, and the limitations of the triple-buffering scheme android uses. Most (all?) devices simply are not going to give you a way to synchronously force-update the screen; the same is effectively true for PCs running Windows.

Comment: Then, the question is, do you want A.) 0 latency (which is unachievable, as I have described), or do you want B.) simply to ensure that the 7 traces are in-sync with each other, at the moment they are drawn on the screen?

Comment: A) I know I cannot achieve 0 latency ... but I want to minimize it at maximum possible. (I have tried several approaches with 60fps and a buffer of amplitudes - that works good). B) Yes. You are right. This is what I want: all 7 traces to be in-sync with each other (when they are drawn on the screen). And calling invalidate() for each Canvas/View does not guarantee the ,,sync”.

Comment: I'll need this question nailed down more before I attempt an answer. 1.) I assume you have chosen to scroll the trace leftwards, continuously, rather than "drawing over it" like this [heart monitor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEb4kojtVHw)? 2.) Most devices can easily re-draw 7 graph lines of say, 5000 pts each, within the 16.6ms per-frame limit. In the event some of the traces get "missed", and get pushed until the next refresh, it is extremely unlikely a human would be able to perceive the slight horizontal misalignment that results. Is it really worth this trouble?

Comment: @greeble31 1) I am scrolling the trace leftwards after reaching Canvas.Width. (if (x >= Canvas.Width) x = 0;) For the efect of scrolling, I am drawing a black rectangle of 12px width right after the current cursor (x value).  2) It's okay. In fact, I have tried that scenario and I am satisfied. The only problem is: How can I draw in sequence 7 canvases when I receive a new struct of new amplitudes (byte[7])? Invalidate() on each View does not guarantee the sync. (because it depends on the OnDraw() scheduling of each entity).

Comment: Also, I want to avoid one "big" Canvas (and drawing each channel into regions), because the channels should be somehow modular (I will have at least 3 layouts using different channels) - I will need to code the logic for each layout even though we are talking about the same content....

Comment: Ah, so you are doing it rather like the heart monitor video. That changes things. Could you please explain - in as much detail as possible - what problem/fault occurs when you find that your `onDraw()` calls have occurred in an out-of-sync manner? Screenshots if possible, please.